# Create variables at runtime with ID that can be referenced

Tags: c#, variables, types

I am creating a 3D modeling app that will store the vertex points in a bunch of variables, one for each. I need to be able to dynamically add or remove vertex points which calls for dynamically adding or removing these variables. Each face will reference these points with an ID linking to the variable containing the point coordinates. Is there a way to create and destroy variables at runtime? Is there a better way to accomplish this with an existing data type? I don't think an array will work because these need to be independent in order to be added or removed easily. I also can't directly store the coordinates of the points because a floating point error or other small change would make duplicate points next to each other.

Comment: You are probably looking for `Dictionary<string, YourVertexType>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `Dictionary` (as Alexei pointed out in his comment).  A Dictionary is very fast for adding, removing and retrieving values.

As for the key, options include

- A sequential `int`
- A `long` that is a hash based on data in the vertex
- Worst case a Guid

A sequential `int` would work well in many use cases, though if you have multiple threads requesting new IDs you would have slight contention getting the next ID (and be sure you follow best practices for threading).

A `long` hash risks collisions, e.g. if the hash is derived from the coordinates and you can have multiple vertices under management with the same coordinates (vertices with different coordinates run the normal risk of hash collisions).

A `Guid` is pretty large for a key, especially if there are many points, but is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "Guid is pretty large" do you mean in terms of memory? Would this really matter if there are only a few thousands vertex points in the scene?

Comment: Yes in terms of memory, but if you have a few thousand on a modern computer that will not matter.  There is also a slight cost to compute the hash of the Guid when accessing the Dictionary (an int and long use their actual value as the hash key).  That cost is trivial unless the Dictionary is being accessed over and over in a tight loop (in which case I would benchmark the cost to see if it matters in the context of your application).